# Is there a functionality in Java similar to C#'s anonymous types?

Tags: java, anonymous-types

I was wondering if there exists a similar functionality in Java similar to C#'s anonymous types:

`var a = new {Count = 5, Message = "A string."};`

Or does this concept go against the Java paradigm?

**EDIT:**

I suppose using `Hashable()` in Java is somewhat similar.

Comment: Anonymous types were added to support LINQ, since one of its most common use cases was projecting elements of one sequence to another. If you tell us how you would like to use them, perhaps we could suggest a good alternative.

Comment: In most cases Map is better than Hashtable. Look at example in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you mean sth like this:

```
Object o = new Object(){
    int count = 5;
    String message = "A string.";
};
```

**@Commenters**: of course this is a theoretical, very inconvenient example.

Probably OP may use `Map`:

```
Map<String,Object> a = new HashMap<String,Object>();
a.put("Count", 5);
a.put("Message", "A string.");

int count = (Integer)a.get("Count"); //better use Integer instead of int to avoid NPE
String message = (String)a.get("Message");
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can't do e.g. `o.count` after that - the attributes would be useless.

Comment: Yea there is no way to get those back. Ever. Again.

Comment: @delnan I suppose you could reflect on it if you knew the names.

Comment: @defnan the attributes are not useless. Object 0 = new Object() { int count = 0 ; public String toString ( ) { return "This object has been toString'ed " + (count++) + " times." ; }

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: there many ways to get those attrs back (e.g. reflection, AspectJ, other bytecode instrumentation..). But this is only theoretical example. Using e.g. Map would be better solution.

Comment: @asawyer: you event don't have to know the names. `o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` will work here.

Comment: @zacheusz Gotcha. I'm not familiar with the java reflection api is all. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @zacheusz The declared fields are useless unless they are also declared public.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: look at this snippet: `Object o = new Object(){private int count = 5;};Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("count");f.setAccessible(true);int c = f.getInt(o);` I know that is strange, unconvenient and slow. But it works ;)  BTW I've added example with `Map` to my response.

Comment: @zacheusz, don't get into the habit of suppressing member visibility.  Just declare it public.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: as I said this is totally theoretical example and BTW (in first example) I declared it default, not private. It is enough for this example. So your sentence "The declared fields are useless unless they are also declared public." in fact refers to package scoped fields. And I think that this is offtopic now ;)

Comment: it is similar but not the same

Answer (score 15):

No.  There is no equivalent.  There is no typeless variable declaration (`var`) in Java that the Java compiler could fill in with the auto-generated type name to allow `a.Count` and `a.Message` to be accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Java has a feature called local classes, which are somewhat similar. They're useful for creating a class or implementing an interface that doesn't really need to be known about outside of a particular method. The scope of the local class is limited by the code block that defines it.

```
public void doSomething() {
    class SomeLocalClass {
        public int count = 5;
        public String message = "A string.";
    }

    SomeLocalClass local = new SomeLocalClass();
    System.out.println(local.count);
    System.out.println(local.message);
}
```

Unlike anonymous types in C#, Java local classes and their fields have explicitly defined types, but I imagine they might have some overlapping use cases.

Comment: That's quite close to what I was looking for when I encountered this question. :)