# Transform list to mapping using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following pattern repeated throughout my code:

```
class X<T, V>
{
    V doTransform(T t) {
        return null; // dummy implementation
    }

    Map<T, V> transform(List<T> item) {
        return item.stream().map(x->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x, doTransform(x))).collect(toMap(x->x.getKey(), x->x.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Requiring the use of AbstractMap.SimpleEntry is messy and clunky. Linqs use of anonymous types is more elegant.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this using streams?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `doTransform` in the value mapper:

```
Map<T, V> transform(List<T> item) {
    return item.stream().collect(toMap(x -> x, x -> doTransform(x)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't have an exact equivalent of C#'s anonymous types.

In this specific case, you don't need the intermediate `map` operation as @Jorn Vernee has suggested. instead, you can perform the key and value extraction in the `toMap` collector.

However, when it gets to cases where you think you need something as such of C#'s anonymous types you may consider:

1. [anonymous objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794192/is-there-a-functionality-in-java-similar-to-cs-anonymous-types) (may not always be what you want depending on your use case)
2. `Arrays.asList(...)`, `List.of(...)` (may not always be what you want depending on your use case)
3. an array (may not always be what you want depending on your use case)

Ultimately, If you *really* need to map to something that can contain two different types of elements then I'd stick with the `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

That, said your current example can be simplified to:

```
Map<T, V> transform(List<T> items) {
    return items.stream().collect(toMap(Function.identity(),this::doTransform));
}
```

Comment: Nice!, I was probably a little lazy with my answer ;) There's also the `Map.entry()` factory method since Java 9, which is a little shorter.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, there is no need to do the intermediate storage at all:

```
Map<T, V> transform(List<T> item) {
    return item.stream().collect(toMap(x -> x, x -> doTransform(x)));
}
```

But if you need it, Java 9 offers a simpler factory method,

```
Map<T, V> transform(List<T> item) {
    return item.stream()
               .map(x -> Map.entry(x, doTransform(x)))
               .collect(toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue()));
}
```

as long as you don’t have to deal with `null`.

You can use an anonymous inner class here,

```
Map<T, V> transform(List<T> item) {
    return item.stream()
               .map(x -> new Object(){ T t = x; V v = doTransform(x); })
               .collect(toMap(x -> x.t, x -> x.v));
}
```

but it’s less efficient. It’s an inner class which captures a reference to the surrounding `this`, also it captures `x`, so you have two fields, `t` and the synthetic one for capturing `x`, for the same thing.

The latter could be circumvented by using a method, e.g.

```
Map<T, V> transform(List<T> item) {
    return item.stream()
               .map(x -> new Object(){ T getKey() { return x; } V v = doTransform(x); })
               .collect(toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.v));
}
```

But it doesn’t add to readability.

The only true anonymous types are the types generated for lambda expressions, which could be used to store information via higher order functions:

```
Map<T, V> transform(List<T> item) {
    return item.stream()
               .map(x -> capture(x, doTransform(x)))
               .collect(HashMap::new, (m,f) -> f.accept(m::put), HashMap::putAll);
}
```

```
public static <A,B> Consumer<BiConsumer<A,B>> capture(A a, B b) {
    return f -> f.accept(a, b);
}
```

but you’d soon hit the limitations of Java’s type system (it still isn’t a functional programming language) if you try this with more complex scenarios.